# get_posts from post x(offset=>x) to end

Tags: get-posts

How can i get the posts using get_posts from let's say post 10 and beyond?So if i have 200 posts i will get from post 10 to post 200(190 posts)?

Because as i see if i use

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'offset'          => 10
    ); ?>
```

i just get all the posts

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange, you'd have thought if you disable paging and grab all posts, that you could naturally set an offset to, eg.

```
array( 'nopaging' => true, 'offset' => 10 )
```

or

```
array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset' => 10 )
```

or

```
array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'offset' => 10 )
```

This unfortunately doesn't appear to work(bug / oversight in core i'd guess), however the following works, which i'd agree is not perfect, but will work.

```
array( 'posts_per_page' => 100000, 'offset' => 10 )
```

Just use a really high number, and it'll work around the issue of the `offset` not being respected when paging is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $key => $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    if( $key > 10 )

    // let do it

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've never tried it berfore, I hope this helps.

Comment: It's not what i'm asking for because i don't want this extra looping but +1 for the try

Comment: sry buddy if i made a mistake

Comment: it's ok.Don't mentioned it